# Why folder id is null when I try to create folder?

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I use this code:

```
$folder = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile([
  'name' => 'Invoices',
  'mimeType' => 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'
]);

$req = $service->files->create($folder, [
  'fields' => 'id'
]);

var_dump($req->id); //NULL
```

Api version: v3.
Id is always null, but files uploading successfully.

Comment: wrap your code in try-catch block

Comment: @Deep, I wrapped my code, nothing changes. No exceptions.

Comment: I rewrite my code. Now I send request via $client->authorize().

    $res = $client->authorize()->send($req);

Folders created but response haven't id field.

Answer (score 0):

Please try using the suggested code in [Creating a folder](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/folder#creating_a_folder) wherein you need to insert a file with this MIME type and a folder title using array of Strings representing a file's parent folders

```
$fileMetadata = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(array(
  'name' => 'Invoices',
  'mimeType' => 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'));
$file = $driveService->files->create($fileMetadata, array(
  'fields' => 'id'));
printf("Folder ID: %s\n", $file->id);
```